# MVC4 How to get the data in partial view when parent view click submit

Tags: model-view-controller, view, parent, partial

MVC4 How to get the data in partial view when parent view click submit

I create a edit page for user update the data, the parent view show some of book details and partial view is a loop show the status of each book. Also, the parent view have a submit button for update both of partial view and parent view, but when I click the submit only parent view data can update and partial view still not update. The code below:

Model:

```
public class LibraryInventory
{
      public decimal LibraryID { get; set; }
      public string Title { get; set; }
      public List<LibraryItem> Entities { get; set; }
}

public class LibraryItem
{     public decimal StatusID { get; set; }
      public string Location { get; set; }
      public decimal BorrowedBy { get; set; }
}
```

Controller :

```
public ActionResult EditRecord(string ID)
{    
     DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["EditGridData"];
     LibraryInventory record = new LibraryInventory(dt.Rows[0]);
     dt = LibraryEditBLL.GetEditItems(ID);
     if (results.ToList().Count > 0)
     {
          record.Entities = LibraryItem.ConvertToLibraryEntity(dt).ToList();
     }
     return View(record);
}


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditRecord(string FormButton, LibraryInventory model)
{   
     switch (FormButton)
     {    
       case "Submit":                    
           if (ModelState.IsValid)
           {       
               LibraryEditBLL.UpdateInventoryLibrary(model);
           }
           return View("EditRecord",record);
      default:
           return RedirectToAction("Edit"); //other page not need check
 }
```

View :

```
 @model XXX.Models.LibraryModels.LibraryInventory                             
 @using (Html.BeginForm("EditRecord", "Library", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })){
 @Html.HiddenFor(m =>m.LibraryID)
 <table>
     <tr>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Title)</td> 
        @for (var i = 0; i < @Model.Entities.Count; i++)
        {
            @Html.Partial("EditItem", @Model.Entities[i])

        }
     </tr>
 </table>
  }




  @model XXX.Models.LibraryModels.LibraryItem
  <tr>
      <td> @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.StatusID) </td>
      <td> @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Location)</td>
      <td> @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.BorrowedBy) </td>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for your view. And no need of partialview for this simple scenario.

```
@model XXX.Models.LibraryModels.LibraryInventory                             
@using (Html.BeginForm("EditRecord", "Library", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })){
@Html.HiddenFor(m =>m.LibraryID)
<table>
 <tr>
    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Title)</td> 
 </tr>
    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Entities.Count; i++)
    {          
     <tr>
         <td> @Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.Entities[i].StatusID) </td>
          <td> @Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.Entities[i].Location)</td>
            <td> @Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.Entities[i].BorrowedBy) </td>

     </tr>
    }

</table>
 }
```